# Apple approval for app with GPPSignIn

Tags: ios, google-plus

Is it possible to use [GPPSignIn](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in) and be approved by the app store?

Apple doesn't approve apps with login processes that redirect users outside of the app.

GPPSignIn redirects users outside of the app during login.

> It provides single sign-on via the Google+ app (if installed), Chrome
>   for iOS (if installed), or Mobile Safari.

What gives?  Is Google pushing an iOS API that cannot be used for an approved iOS app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update to GIDSignIn. It allows you to choose whether you want to sign in via another app or via web view.
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

Comment: If you already have developed with GPPSignIn, there are a couple steps you need to do to switch over to using GIDSignIn: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide

Comment: So, yes an app using GPPSignIn will be rejected from by Apple's App Store?

Comment: @StevenWexler, not just GPPSignIn, but any app that performs sign in by opening safari, and then redirecting back to that app. Apple wants you to login without leaving the app, for example, by loading the login page inside of UIWebView.